# Define function signature to prohibit some data types using type constructors

Tags: scala

I have scala input structures like this:

```
List(List(1, 2, 3), 3.0, false, List(2.32, 6.36, List(List(1))))
```

or

```
List(List(1, 2, 3), 3.0, false, List(2.32, 6.36, List(List(1, "", Some(false)))))
```

There can be any number of nested Lists, containing only **numbers** in the first example
and containing **non numeric** types in second one.

I would like to allow in method signature only inputs like the first one, only with **numbers** and to get its sum for example:

```
def sum[T <: Number](list: List[F[_]]): Number
```

and get the sum of its elements and compilation failed if I pass the second one (with String and Boolean or any other **non numeric** Object type )

I have this:

```
def sum[T <: Any](list: List[T]): Double = {
    def flatten(ls: List[Any]): List[_] = {
      ls flatMap {
        case i: List[_] => flatten(i)
        case e @ (_:Short | _:Byte | _:Int | _:Long | _:Double | _:Float) => List(e)
        case _ => List()
      }
    }
    flatten(list).foldLeft(0D) {(summ, el) => summ + el.doubleValue }
  }
```

It works in runtime but it doesn't fail when I pass both.
I want to pass only Lists containing numbers.

Comment: Why do you want this specific thing ? That `input` is something which you should really avoid in Scala. That input is just plain `List[Any]`.

Comment: I know it. You're right about ```List[Any]```. Just to learn scala's powerful typesystem.

Comment: You are not using any of that "power". This (java like thing) is exactly what you are not supposed to do in Scala because you have such powerful type system. You are just taking a `List[Any]` then doing a runtime check weather its a `List` or `AnyVal` (ignoring other cases).

Comment: I understand. This is why I'm asking you or somebody.

Comment: The proper way of doing it would be introducing a custom structure (algebraic data type) representing your intents and preserving whatever constraint you want. It's a tree-like structure, not a `List` really.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand why would you want to do this.

But let's say that you need something like this then you can do it with compile time checks like following (this is going to be tricky).

NOTE: tested with Scala 2.12.14 and 2.13.6; will not work at all with Scala 3; might require some minor changes for earlier versions of 2.12.x or 2.13.x line.

First we need to define the `CanBeUsed` restriction,

```
trait CanBeUsed[A] {
  // carry the type through type erasure
  type AType = A

  def reduceToDouble(a: A): Double
}

object CanBeUsed {
  // create CanBeUsed instances only for allowed types
  implicit val intCanBeUsed: CanBeUsed[Int] = a => a.toDouble
  implicit val doubleCanBeUsed: CanBeUsed[Double] = a => a

  implicit val listOfIntCanBeUsed: CanBeUsed[List[Int]] = a => a.sum.toDouble
  implicit val listOfDoubleCanBeUsed: CanBeUsed[List[Double]] = a => a.sum
}
```

Then we need to define a builder which will allow us to create a "restricted list"

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable

class InputListBuilder {
  // we are using existential type here
  private val listBuffer = mutable.ListBuffer.empty[InputListBuilder.LBT[_]]

  // only those `A` which have an implicit CanBeUsed[A] will be allowed
  def append[A <: Any](a: A)(implicit canBeUsed: CanBeUsed[A]): InputListBuilder = {
    listBuffer.append((a, canBeUsed))
    this
  }

  def build: List[InputListBuilder.LBT[_]] = listBuffer.toList
}

object InputListBuilder {
  // type lambda for InputList type
  type LBT[A <: Any] = ({ type L = (A, CanBeUsed[A]) })#L
}
```

Now, we can define our `sum` like following,

```
object SumUtil {
  def sum(list: List[InputListBuilder.LBT[_]]): Double = {
    list.foldLeft(0d) { (acc, el) => 
      acc + el._2.reduceToDouble(el._1.asInstanceOf[el._2.AType]) 
    }
  }
}
```

Usage,

```scala
val list1 =
  new InputListBuilder()
    .append(1)
    .append(1.1d)
    .append(List(1, 2))
    .append(List(1.1d, 2.2d))
    .build
// list1: List[InputListBuilder.LBT[_]] = List((1,CanBeUsed$<function>), (1.1,CanBeUsed$<function>), (List(1, 2),CanBeUsed$<function>), (List(1.1, 2.2),CanBeUsed$<function>))

// this list2 will not be allowed by the compiler
// val list2 =
//   new InputList()
//     .append("abc")
//     .append(List("abc"))
//     .build

val list1Sum = SumUtil.sum(list1)
// list1Sum: Double = 8.4
```

Comment: I like this approach